# How to display html with css stylesheet in TextView?

Tags: android, html, css, spannable

Converting html file to spanned object and displaying it in TextView works fine but what if I want to also apply css styles? 
I've tried to combine css styles with html file but styles ale ignored by Html.fromHtml() method.

How can I display text modified by css styles in my TextView?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://morse.swirski.name/pastes/d7poit8th7f0kx0qs6yuav5r3mpq8h7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what if I want to also apply css styles?

That is not supported by `Html.fromHtml()`. You will need to build your own HTML/CSS parser and build your own formatted string, perhaps using `SpannableStringBuilder`.